# How can I extract the words from this string " !!one!! **two** @@three@@" using Regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

In IRB, I can do this:
   c = /(\b\w+\b)\W*(\b\w+\b)\W*(\b\w+\b)\W*/.match(" !!one** **two** @@three@@ ")

And get this:
=> MatchData "one** **two** @@three@@ " 1:"one" 2:"two" 3:"three"

But assuming I don't know the number of words in advance, how can I still extract all words out of the string". For example, it might be " !!one** **two** @@three@@ " in one instance, but might be " !!five** **six** " in another instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
> " !!one** *two* @@three@@ ".scan(/\w+/)
=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Also, `scan` can return array of arrays in case of using `()`.

```
> "Our fifty users left 500 posts this month.".scan(/([a-z]+|\d+)\s+(posts|users)/i)
=> [["fifty", "users"], ["500", "posts"]]
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812